# What's the usual direction of bit-rot on a hard disk (from inactivity)?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, file-corruption

I opened 2 copies of the same file from around 6 years ago. There was a hash mismatch and I found a single bit difference between the two files when I open the file up in a visual hexadecimal file difference viewer.

Now if I assume this has happened entirely due to inactivity and not due to error, then which would be considered the correct version of the file?

- 36 ( 0011 0110 )
- 3E ( 0011 1110 )

What should the 5th bit be? 0 or 1? Note that I was using a WD Green 2TB from 7 years ago (WD20EZRX).

Brute-force is one thing but knowing the direction of rot may actually help may help in recovering small bits of mismatching data. Hence all help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I guess this would depend on the exact hardware and hard disk controller used - the disk doesn't contain 0 or 1, it contains iron with a magnetic field, and the controller interprets the field direction as 0 or 1. It could well depend on how the disk was stored relative to the earth's magnetic field... But probably it is completely random anyway.

Comment: Yeah that's the hard part. But fortunately, all the mismatches in those folders seem to correspond to the same direction. All of the mismatching bits are 0 in one folder, 1 in the other. I guess I'll keep looking around for other mismatches. If I get lucky with a 3rd file, I could use it as reference, and then maybe I'll be able to determine the rot direction.

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted for closing. If the answer was easy, I wouldn't be asking here. I certainly have been haunted by this question for a long time. And it may shed some light on the topic for others wondering the same.

Comment: I suspect the close vote is not because the question is simply "hard" but because it is impossible to give a definitive answer. Consumers are at the whims of how manufacturers decide to store a bit on a disk and different revisions of controller or head could easily decide to switch what type of field constitutes a "1" or a "0". Due to a disk also being a collection of fields and data it could be affected by the data around it and local magnetic fields as well as cosmic rays and other random events. I doubt anyone can shed more than a dim candle of light into this dark void.

Comment: That's not to say your question is "bad" but the close reason selected was "**Opinion-based**  This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers." And that feels right, it is impossible to give a definitive answer that doesn't have a million caveats of "worked on my machine", "changed in hardware rev 2 so it's wrong now". You can ask a good question, but in this case only the engineer who knows the material science of a particular drive would know the answer and he could be wrong for the next drive.

Comment: Our opinion does not change the manufacturer's way of storing data. My question asks for 'usual' in which case the answer would be along the lines of "it's mostly 'this' but, it has been change around 'that' time to the other one, and x, y, z cases still use the old method." THAT would be a fact based answer. Human opinions DO NOT change the facts. I'm not asking what cpu is better intel or amd. I'm asking where 0 is used and where 1 is used as default.

Comment: The question is hard BECAUSE you need the right kind of persons with the knowledge required to answer this question. I don't need opinions. I need straight hard facts. Opinions won't recover my data for me.

Comment: Professionals with access to your hardware will recover your data. Look up either a local data recovery service or send it to someone. Don't delete this because it's closed, I think it's a good question